# Strange, IPhone performSelector on sub-thread doesn't work.

Tags: iphone, multithreading, selector

I want to do some action on a thread using the following API, so strange selector poiOneBoxSearch hasn't been invoked, why? Any mistake on the code?  Thanks.

```
- (void)poiOneBoxSearch{
     [self poiOneBoxSearcWithQueryString:@"coffee" isFinished:YES];
}

- (void)test1{
     NSThread* thread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
     [self performSelector:@selector(poiOneBoxSearch)
               onThread:thread
             withObject:nil
          waitUntilDone:YES];
     [thread release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want use   **performSelector** Method You should Read below Link 
,I Think You missed SOmething

[Please Goes Through This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If Not you may Use Below Code.

Try This

```
 - (void)test1{
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(poiOneBoxSearch) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 }
```

Comment: This worked when called from a background thread when many of the other options didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(poiOneBoxSearch) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(poiOneBoxSearch) withObject:nil];

- (void) poiOneBoxSearch{
          @autoreleasepool { 
     [self poiOneBoxSearcWithQueryString:@"coffee" isFinished:YES];
} }
```

The most important thing that you have to keep in mind is that since this method creates a thread on the given selector, the selector must have an autorelease pool just like any other thread in a reference-counted memory environment.